# execCommand("copy") not working in mobile

Tags: html, jquery

For Copy a input field text i used "execCommand("copy")" but in mobile its not working. Anyone have idea then let me know

Below is my Js function :

```
function coupon_coode_custom() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
//   alert(copyText)
  copyText.focus();
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

html Code as follow :

```
<div class="coupon_copy">
<input type="text" value="abc" id="myInput"> 
<button onclick="coupon_coode_custom()">Copy text</button>
</div>
```

I want to copy value of input. In desktop its working fine but in mobile its not working. If anyone have idea then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against using `execCommmand` as it has been deprecated according to the documentation.

"This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand